# How can I empty the field of the form after submit?

Tags: reactjs

How can I **empty** the 'city' **field** after **click button** 'Get Weather'? and I have to **click twice** to the **button** to get the **correct 'time'**
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csq2Q.jpg)

**code link :** [project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44hsh37w0yxzmt5/weather-arabic2.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
  const element = e.target.elements.city;
  const city = element.value;

  // after data fetching or at once
  element.value="";
```

Also read docs about [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Comment: Thank you this is work for empty city field but is still the **time** is not exactly (in **Details**)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("city").value = ""
```

--- This will work if it is an input field, or text area.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply write `"name_of_object".setText(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 
<p>Enter some text in the fields below,
then press the "Reset form" button to 
reset the form.</p>
 
<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Reset form">
</form>
 
<script>
function submit() {
  /*Put all the data posting code here*/
 document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```